# React-native upgrade from 0.61.5 to 0.63.2: TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to upgrade  React-native from 0.61.5 to 0.63.2.
For iOS everything is ok.  But for Android I've got:

1. Current errors while building bundle:

   ERROR    TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

   ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

   ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2. White screen on emulator

I deleted the app, cleaned the solution - not working.

Updated by this manual: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.63.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating dependencies and devDependencies to the latest versions. I guess the better solution would be to find out what exactly one needed to be update. But the main thing for now is that app finally runs :)